# Country song, c.1999 - "Love is ___"

Tags: identify-this-song, identify-this-genre

I heared this song in 1999 in Saudi Arabia. It was performed by a man. Aired on 91.4 FM local Dhahran Station (Aramco Radio).

It could be a country song, but I could be wrong.

The part of lyrics I remember is something like:

> "Love is _____ , Love is ______ , Love is why I wrote/sing this song "...

I am not sure if he says (wrote/sing) but I am sure he said

> (love is why I (verb) this song).

Comment: Was it sung by a man or a woman? Do you remember further details about the music?

Comment: It was by a man. I am not sure if he said (wrote) or (sing) but I am sure he said (love is why I (verb) this song) @Marzipanherz

Comment: @Ahmad, please edit the question and add all the details you can. Was it on radio, on TV, in a movie/TV show, in which country etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Clint Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clint_Black) is an american **country** singer.

His song '[Something that we do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_That_We_Do)' was released in **1997** and contains the [lines](http://www.metrolyrics.com/something-that-we-do-lyrics-clint-black.html)

> Love is wide, love is long
>
> Love is deep and love is strong
>
> **Love is why I love this song**
>
> And I hope you love it too

Thus, I guess this might be the song you are looking for.